# Connecting bluetooth keyboard ubuntu 13.10 org.bluez.Input method not found

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to connect a Logitech keyboard using Bluetooth. I can't get this to work by means of the GUI so I used my console to follow this approach: http://devasive.blogspot.be/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html

It adds the device and sets the trusted flag. Then it uses

```
sudo bluez-test-input connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

but this python program fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/bluez-test-input", line 42, in <module> input.Connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__ return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__ **keywords)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method Connect" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Input" doesn't exist
```

It seems that input has no Connect method. I pulled the piece of python out of the file and is goes as follows:

```
input = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", device),
            "org.bluez.Input")

if args[0] == "connect":
    input.Connect()
```

Is there any way to see what org.bluez.Input interface on that input object looks like. The bluez website is of little help as are all other posts on the subject. The documentation of bluez version 4.101 specify that the objects of the type org.bluez.Input have a connect method. I checked that the Input plugin is not disabled in the config file as well. Is upgrading to bluez 5 going to help me?

Edit:

On my laptop with the same version of ubuntu but an internal bluetooth module, it worked flawless. I think this might be the problem:

```
hciconfig -a hci0

...
Service Classes: Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
...
```

I see no Input service class. Input is needed by keyboard and mouse. Does this mean the bluetooth dongle does not support this or is it something else?

Kind regards,

Roel Storms